# Flash - Text overlaps in a text box

Tags: flash-cs5

The image below should say enough.

When trying to go to the next line using enter it goes on top of (slightly lower) than the text line above it.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_05_2012/post-303110-13359838269609.png.pagespeed.ce.xEvMztZ7Ot.png

Comment: Very unclear image/question. I'd love to help but please rephrase.

Comment: Say that I'm typing in a text box, and I hit enter for a new line, the text goes underneath the text above it, but overlaps the text above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the character properties of the textfield, check your **Leading** (it's a percentile value next to the font size). This sets the line height of a textfield.

Default value is 100%.